# HierarchyViewer cant't inspect layout in PopupWindow

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

I'm using [`ViewServer`](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) to inspect layout in my app.I click a button and it shows a `PopupWindow` as Dropdown. But I can't see the popup window layout in `HierarchyViewer`.

Any help?

Comment: hierarchyviewer shows windows,  a PopupWindow is ... hmm ... a window so it doesn't  belong to activity window

Comment: is there a way to make this?

Comment: yes,  show a popup and resrart hierarchyviewer

Comment: that's not working if I use hierarchyviewer.bat from commandline. But the new plugin in ddms is somehow useless.

Comment: what's  not working? just use "focused window" from the list of windows

Comment: I didn't find "list of windows"(using hierarchyviewer.bat). can you show me a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

After showing the window, add the below statement and relaunch HierarchyViewer. It should show a your pop window contents.

```
ViewServer.get(context).addWindow(popupWindow.getContentView(), "popup");
```

On your onDismissListener, add the following statement to remove the views from hierarchyviewer.

```
ViewServer.get(context).removeWindow(window.getContentView());
```